# Could not open a connection to sql server[xampp]

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I installed the 
"PHP for SQL Server"
 and
 " ODBC Driver 11"

but then I got this message.

> Connection could not be established. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>
>   08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 67 [code] => 67 [2] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could
>   not open a connection to SQL Server [67]. [message] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could
>   not open a connection to SQL Server [67]. ) [1] => Array ( [0] =>
>   HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired [message] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired ) [2]
>   => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 67 [code] => 67 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection
>   to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if
>   instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
>   [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A
>   network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
>   Server Books Online. ) )

The  connection code I'm using

```
$serverName = "localhost/sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"company", "UID"=>"root", "PWD"=>"");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
    echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Please help, it's the first time using  sql server so I don't know what to do !

Comment: Are you sure your SQL server is up and running?

Comment: I'm using xampp  so I'm sure it's running. I don't know if I have to run a separate server for sql!

Comment: As far as i know - xampp doesn't install sql server...

Comment: I saw many people using it  in Xampp.  anyway Thank you I think I will switch xampp.

Comment: not sure what you are talking about. sql sever != mysql server. you should double check.

Comment: Thank you for your tip I  installed Microsoft server and it works now 0__0. I was trying to use  phpmyadmin.  Thanksss

Comment: phpmyadmin is for mysql, not for ms sql server.